# How to keep my overlay on top while another app is in Full Screen mode?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, overlay

I'm working on an app (macOS, SwiftUI) that presents an overlay window for other apps.

So far, my overlay window appears on top of all other apps and follows the focused screen, but when another app is in Full Screen mode, my window doesn't appear on top anymore.
How can I fix this?

Here is the code I currently have:

```
import SwiftUI
    
struct ContentView: View {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)

        if let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first {
            window.isOpaque = false
            window.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear

            // Remove the title bar
            window.styleMask = [.borderless, .fullSizeContentView]

            // Keep the content but make the window background transparent
            window.contentView?.wantsLayer = true
            window.contentView?.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor

            // Keep window above all other and ignore mouse events
            window.level = NSWindow.Level.screenSaver
            window.ignoresMouseEvents = true

            // Keep the window on all spaces
            window.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenPrimary]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSWindow.Level.screenSaver` is not the highest level available, it has a `rawValue` of 101. you could experiment setting higher values with:

```
window.level = NSWindow.Level(rawValue: 1000)
```

Comment: I stoped working on the project but thank you for the proposition